# import tf segfaults python on OS X 10.9 with brewed python

Tags: ros, python, homebrew, osx, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I revently got the desktop-full variant of ROS hydro installed on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks. There were a series of smaller issues, e.g. most of the ones mentioned at
http://answers.ros.org/question/94771/building-octomap-orocos_kdl-and-other-packages-on-osx-109-solution/, but in the end I got everything to compile.

When I start up python and type `import tf`, it crashes with

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

My python version is 2.7.6 from homebrew. I don't even know how to start debugging this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

This seems to be caused by faulty cmake find_package(PythonLibs), which in turn caused by _tf.so to be linked against apple's python, while I'm using brewed python. I opened this issue: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/25118.

I guess the question that remains is if anybody else has the same issue. For me it is not isolated to tf, but all python modules that are built with find_package(PythonLibs) and link against the found python libs.

**Edit2:**

[moved to new question]

**Edit3:**

When used to be Edit2 is now a new question as suggested. Thanks.

http://answers.ros.org/question/110671/recommended-python-version-on-os-x-with-homebrew/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108431/import-tf-segfaults-python-on-os-x-10.9-with-brewed-python/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-12-10**:
Unless you have a reason for using the Homebrew Python, I would highly recommend using the built-in Python, in my experience it causes far fewer issues.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-12-13**:
I think Edit2 above should be asked as a new question.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-11**:
Can you edit the wiki to reflect that?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-11**:
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Mavericks with the system python (2.7.5), and I don't have this problem.

Unless you know of a very specific reason that you need python 2.7.6 instead of 2.7.5, I strongly suggest removing your homebrew install of python and using the system version instead.

I would try this out by doing `brew unlink python` and confirm that the system python interpreter does what you want. You can then remove python with `brew uninstall python` or re-enable your homebrew python install with `brew link python`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
I'll accept this since it sort of works around the issue. Beware that you have to reinstall various formulas, as well as pip packages and recompile ROS when switching python between brewed and system.

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-12-16**:
I also get Segmentation fault when running stereo image proc on Mac OSX with system python. If  someone have any ideas how to resolve it, will very appreciate it!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
You should add a question for that specific problem. What does the OS X problem report state?

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-12-16**:
I have had this problem for a long time on OSX. I am thinking about debugging it. I don't have the cameras around to try it. Will create a question soon. Thank you!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-17**:
I wounder if this could ne related to this issue with message filters, since stereo image proc is using the approx time policy.  You could try patching that header file locally. https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/326

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-12-17**:
It looks like the problem was in the topic I was subscribing. Because my image_raw originally grayscale I should have subscribed to image_rect instead of image_rect_color. So no segmentation fault for now. :)